# How can I use Ninject in a Visual Studio test project

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2, ninject

I have a testing project which I want to be able to use dependency injection like I do in my Web Api project. The way I do it there is as follows in the Startup.cs class:

```
app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => NinjectConfig.CreateKernel.Value);
app.UseNinjectWebApi(config);
```

I am using Ninject and I'd like to know how can I apply this in my test project which doesn't have such structure but I'd like it to use DI, too.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Ninject or a standard DI container framework, I'd recommend taking a look at the excellent and open source [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture). Which is kind of like DI for tests on steroids (it actually helps you generate the dependencies). It also comes along with a whole bunch of auto mocking stuff, and is probably going to involve less friction than implementing a di solution in your tests where typically you will want to switch out the dependencies depending on the test case etc...